# Recording Data of my learning progress

Tags: python, r, data, beginner

I'm just starting out with learning about Data Science and programming through various online course.

Was thinking a good first project would be a to create a log of what I'm learning and how long for and then work out ways that I can visualise this for use in a CV further down the road.

Was wanting to get a rough outline for how you would set a project like this up.

Was thinking of something like a simple site where I click on the learning resource I used and it asks for the amount of time I studied for and then records the data and time. Maybe more inputs for tags and percentage complete etc...

Currently learning R and Python.

So grateful for any ideas or advise you have.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think the first point to address is how employers will know you are being honest about your logging. Maybe a better use of your time is to not put in number of hours, but projects and code references you've made so that the output is more concrete rather than just a number of hours.  The problem is I know plenty of people who put in 1 hour and learn what a normal person would learn in 5 hours. Think about the WOW factor in this.. what would be convincing to employers?

Also, if its only you that are logging in hours and nobody else is going to see or use that program, you might as well use excel while focusing on whatever project you're passionate about.

Comment: Thanks that's a great idea, thanks for the advice. Still having my hand held by online resources. Going to start on a little project and just try and crash it out.

Comment: No prob! Yea I think the best way to learn is to do a tutorial online, think of a very similar problem, and modify the tutorial to address the problem you came up with. Then you get to know the ins and outs of the project being worked on.